# When "humane" doesn't mean "compassionate"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm editing a text (by a non-native speaker of English) that is, in a broad sense, about poetry. One phrase used frequently is "humane eloquence". At first I changed "humane" to "human" in all such instances, but now I have looked it up in the OED and find a second meaning of "humane" (perhaps related to our use of "humanities" to refer to certain fields of study?):

> "2. Designating those texts or branches of study which concern
> humanity, or which (historically) have been regarded as exercising a
> civilizing influence on the student or reader; esp. designating
> classical grammar, rhetoric, or literature."

The examples given include "humane learning", "humane disciplines", and "humane literature."

My question: does this means "humane eloquence" is OK? Or am I right to correct it to "human"?
Example:

> Arguing the inferior status of pre-Quranic verbal media compared to
> the Scripture, the discussion focused on metrically disciplined poetry
> as the highest achievement of humane eloquence.
> Doctrinally, its inferiority to the Quran is established through by
> opposing the Revelation as the text of divine wisdom, clarity,
> truthfulness and eloquence, with poetry as a vain, untruthful and
> stylistically unclear earthly medium designed for amusement.

PS: 50 pages in, I see that the work of poets is now being contrasted to the "miraculous eloquence" of the Quran. So – rather than "humane" – it must be "human," as contrasted to "miraculous" or divine. But happy to be corrected if that sounds wrong!